# Is there a difference between whole bundled angular application and the same app as web component?

Tags: angular, web-component

I've moved my main `AppComponent` from `bootstrap` to `exports` in my app module, created new module that imports my main `AppModule` and uses `createCustomElement` to  register `AppComponent` as Web Component  and builded whole app bootstraping this new module.

So I started wondering is there any difference/gain in having a whole app wrapped in a WebCompoment since the `dist` folder and the usage looks kind of the same after that proces.
In other words is an builded Angular app a webcomponent in fact?

Comment: If the Web Component is the soup, then a Web Component created with Angular, Vue, Lit or whatever is the soup __*plus*__ the pan (and maybe even includes the whole stove)

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seems like there is some major difference - in short - you can't have more than 2 angular apps on same page, but if you build one as web component it works fine.